# Play Store - profile signed up for Beta testing but app page doesn't say "beta tester"

Tags: android, google-play

I've signed up for Beta testing using the opt-in link, I've already been part of internal testing and that was fine, and when I go into play store I don't see "you're a beta tester", and the app is not the one meant for beta. although another phone behaves correctly.

What could be the issue? I tried to clear the cache of Chrome, Play Store and google play services, restart the phone, opt-out and opt-in again, nothing seemed to work.

On the google play console beta track section, I can see the message `1 APK from another track is also being served to users of this track.` but I'm not sure why my phone wouldn't get the beta app, same phone I use for debugging so I know it's compatible.

Cheers

Comment: Do you see this app under "Beta" apps listing? Go to playstore => My Apps & Games => Beta

Comment: I somehow don't have the beta tab

Comment: @PareshMayani we have the app rolled out only to specific countries, had to switch country on my play store account! it finally worked

Comment: that's a good catch though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we have the app rolled out only to specific countries, had to switch country on my play store account and it finally worked